# Como obter o maior valor numérico suportado pelo php?

Tags: php

Existe algum método do php para obter o maior valor número suportado por ele?

Comment: se uma das respostas lhe resolveu o problema marque-a como correta por favor. Leia: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635

Answer (score 6):

O PHP possui a constante pré-definida de [`PHP_INT_MAX`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.constants.php), desde o 5.0.5, e também o [`PHP_INT_MIN`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.constants.php), desde o PHP 7.0. A primeira irá retornar o maior valor possível e a segunda o menor valor possível.

```
<?php

echo 'Máximo: '  .PHP_INT_MAX;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'Minimo: ' . PHP_INT_MIN;
```

[Teste isto aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8af39d564b1d9d9a2c7d2e5e61199261a0e38362)

Normalmente, em sistemas 32 bits irá retornar `2147483647` e `-2147483648`, respectivamente. Enquanto no 64 bits irá retornar `9223372036854775807` e `-9223372036854775808`.

Comment: Valeu pela a ajuda!

Answer (score 5):

Com a constante `PHP_INT_MAX`, que é o maior inteiro suportado nesse interpretador, que é disponível a partir da versão `5.0.5`.

[Exemplo Online](http://ideone.com/etXdfq)

***Referencia:*** [*Constantes Pré-definidas*](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.constants.php)

Comment: Valeu pela a ajuda!

Answer (score 3):

## Inteiros

[Documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

O tamanho de um inteiro é dependente da plataforma, embora um valor máximo de cerca de dois bilhões seja o valor usual (isto é, maior valor sinalizado representado com 32 bits). Plataformas de 64 bits têm um valor máximo próximo de 9e18, exceto no Windows, versões anteriores à PHP 7, que serão sempre 32 bits. PHP não suporta inteiros não sinalizados. O tamanho inteiro pode ser determinado através da constante `PHP_INT_SIZE` e o valor máximo através da constante `PHP_INT_MAX`, desde a versão PHP 5.0.5. A partir da versão PHP 7.0.0, o valor mínimo pode ser obtido através da constante `PHP_INT_MIN`.

## Ponto Flutuante

[Documentação oficial](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php):

O tamanho de um número de ponto flutuante depende da plataforma, sendo o máximo de ~1.8e308 com precisão de 14 dígitos decimais (representação de 64 bits no formato [IEEE 754](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Etsimo1/CMSC455/IEEE-754-2008.pdf)).

> **Aviso**: Números de ponto flutuante tem precisão limitada. Embora dependa do sistema, o PHP geralmente utiliza o formato de precisão dupla do IEEE 754, que trará uma precisão máxima devida a arredondamentos da ordem de 1.11e-16. Operações matemáticas incomuns poderão ocasionar erros maiores, e, claro, a propagação de erros deve ser considerada quando várias operações forem realizadas.
>
> Além disso, números racionais que tem representação exata em números em base 10, como 0.1 ou 0.7, não possuem representação exata em ponto flutuante na base 2, o formato utilizado internamente, não importando o tamanho da mantissa. Portanto não existe conversão para o formato interno sem uma pequena perda de precisão. Isso pode ocasionar resultados confusos: por exemplo, floor((0.1+0.7)*10) normalmente retornará 7, em vez do resultado esperado 8, porque a representação interna final será algo como 7.9999999999999991118....
>
> Então, nunca confie em resultados com números de ponto flutuante até a última casa, e nunca compare números de ponto flutuante em igualdades. Se você realmente precisar de alta precisão, você pode utilizar as [funções matemáticas de precisão arbitrária](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.bc.php) e as funções [gmp](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.gmp.php) estão disponíveis.
>
> Para uma explicação "simples" dessa questão, veja o [guia sobre ponto flutuante](http://floating-point-gui.de/), que também tem o título alternativo de "Porque meus números não somam direito?".