# Passar variável do PHP para o Python com mais de 14 caracteres

Tags: php, python-3.x

Problema ao passar variável Python para PHP com mais de 14 caracteres

Código PHP

```
 $p = 123456789101112
 $pyscript = 'C:\\Users\\python\\teste.py';
 $python = 'C:\\Python34\\python.exe';
 $run = shell_exec("$python $pyscript $p");
```

Código Python

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
```

Se `$p` conter até 14 caracteres, ex: `$p = 1234567891011`, o Python imprime: `1234567891011`

Porém se existir mais de 14, ex: `$p = 12345678910111213`, o Python imprime: `1.2345678910111E+16`

Como vou recuperar o valor exato da variável quando excede 14 caracteres?

Comment: O estranho é que o argumento passado via *shell* será *string*, não um inteiro. Eu executei o código aqui e não tive o problema citado na pergunta. O código é só esse mesmo ou ocultou partes dele?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, você tentou simular com um número maior ou igual a 12345678910111213, pois pode ser uma questão de versão do Python

Comment: @Bacco, estou utilizando o PHP 7.0.4 x86

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está esbarrando num problema de precisão numérica.

O PHP tem como máximo inteiro em 32 bits o valor `2147483647`, em 64 bits o valor `9223372036854775807` e acima disto terá um *float*, com **possível** perda de precisão (vide links ao final da resposta para mais detalhes).

Ocorre que, mesmo que o float possa exibir um número razoável de casas, há uma configuração para exibição destas, que por padrão é `14`. Uma vez ultrapassado este comprimento, a exibição será "abreviada".

Mais especificamente, a diretiva é esta:

<sub>Arquivo php.ini</sub>

```
precision 14
```

Link para o manual:

> [Diretiva `precision`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.precision)

### Usando *strings*:

Uma solução possível é usar uma *string* em vez de número. Passando o valor como *string* a saída é textual, será desconsiderado o armazenamento numérico:

```
 $p = '123456789111315171921'; // note as aspas aqui
 $pyscript = 'C:\\Users\\python\\teste.py';
 $python = 'C:\\Python34\\python.exe';
 $run = shell_exec("$python $pyscript $p");
```

Se precisar realmente trabalhar com números grandes, o PHP tem funções específicas para tal, nas biblioteca BCMATH e GMP (vide links abaixo).

### Links relevantes:

> [Como obter o maior valor numérico suportado pelo php?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183206/70)

> [Qual é o máximo de casas decimais permitidas no float em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136808/70)

> [Precisão arbitrária no PHP com BCMATH](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.bc.php)

> [Precisão arbitrária no PHP com GMP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.gmp.php)

Comment: Perfeito, resolveu o problema, obrigado!